# Proper handling of StaleObjectStateException

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a SQL Server database that can be accessed by multiple programs. The programs are written in C# and use Fluent NHibernate as ORM. But there are objects in the database (called tokens) that, according to domain logic, shouldn't allow concurrent processing of them by several processes / threads etc.

I'm trying to achieve this by NHIbernate version locking. I have the following mapping

```
mapping.OptimisticLock.Version();
mapping.Version(token => token.VersionTimestamp).Generated.Always().UnsavedValue(null).Access.Property().CustomSqlType("timestamp").Nullable();
```

and the following code:

```
var token = Session.Get<Token>(tokenId);

if (token.Status != TokenStatus.Available)
    return new FailedResult("Token not available");

try
{
    token.Status = TokenStatus.Locked;
    Session.SaveOrUpdate(token);
}
catch (StaleObjectStateException)
{
    WriteLogsToDb(); // <- another StaleObjectStateException thrown here
    return new FailedResult("Could not acquire token");
}

ProcessToken(token); // do stuff that isn't allowed to be done concurrently by multiple threads/processes

token.Status = TokenStatus.Available;
Session.SaveOrUpdate(token);

return new SuccessResult();
```

The problem is that after I get a `StaleObjectStateException` I am unable to save anything else into the DB (even entities that have no version mapping). I get another `StaleObjectStateException`. But I really need to write logs and some other stuff into th DB after I was unable to lock the token.

What is the proper way to do it? And what is the reason for such behavior of NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

The Session is UoW that consolidate all changes that you make and accept it during Flush operation. Because you got an exception during Flush (SaveOrUpdate without transaction executes Flush) your object (token) is still marked as Dirty and NH try to save it during next Flush and if it still locked you'v got an exception again.

To avoid this you must remove object from session before save anythig else:

```
try
{
    token.Status = TokenStatus.Locked;
    Session.SaveOrUpdate(token);
}
catch (StaleObjectStateException)
{
    Session.Evict(token); // <- remove token from session

    WriteLogsToDb(); // <- another StaleObjectStateException thrown here
    return new FailedResult("Could not acquire token");
}
```

Comment: Sadly, adding `Session.Evict` or `Session.Refresh` has no effect. What I forgot to mention is that `Session.SaveOrUpdate` is an override which internally creates a transaction, calls NHibernate's  `SaveOrUpdate` and then commits the transaction.

Comment: Please, show me the text of exception that you geting then calling  WriteLogsToDb(). And the code of this method to.

Comment: In Ayende post about concurrency: http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency
I found this:
_If the update fails because the row was updated, we will get a StaleObjectException. Like all exceptions, this will make the session ineligible for use, and you would have to create a new session to handle it._

So you must create a new session to write logs in this situation.